# Is it possible to load the Dataset to Microsoft Azure Machine Learning Studio programmatically?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm working in a `.NET` project where I will generate a dataset. I need to load that dataset into Azure Machine Learning Studio. Is there a way to load that dataset into ML studio programmatically (perhaps with an `apikey` and `RequestURI`) instead of manually loading dataset in the Azure ML Studio?

Comment: quick check -- you're talking about the new Machine Learning Studio and not Machine Learning Studio (classic)?

Comment: it is a lot easier if you're using the new studio instead of the classic version.

Answer (score 2):

It may help you:

```
local_path = 'data/prepared.csv'
dataframe.to_csv(local_path)
upload the local file to a datastore on the cloud
# azureml-core of version 1.0.72 or higher is required
# azureml-dataprep[pandas] of version 1.1.34 or higher is required
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset

subscription_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
resource_group = 'xxxxxx'
workspace_name = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)

# get the datastore to upload prepared data
datastore = workspace.get_default_datastore()

# upload the local file from src_dir to the target_path in datastore
datastore.upload(src_dir='data', target_path='data')
# create a dataset referencing the cloud location
dataset = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files(datastore.path('data/prepared.csv'))
```

reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-register-datasets

There is also *Workspace* class for C#
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.workspace.workspace?view=azure-ml-py

Comment: Can you share if it helped or not?

Comment: maybe let them know that they'll have to use the Python SDK and won't be able to do with .NET? I'm not a .NET dev, so maybe you could suggest a way for them to do this...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of a way to do this with `C#`, but there is an Azure ML extension to the Azure CLI that allows you to [register a Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/reference-azure-machine-learning-cli#dataset-management).

If that's not sufficient, then the Python SDK is definitely the way to go. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60677623/3842610) for more info on that front.